# How to connect this 3 NAV parts to work in any browser?

Tags: html, css

I have copied a Menu from another site. It has 3 parts in it's main Menu NAV. Leftpart, Middle Logo Part & Right Part. But they are not being align when I increase or shrink the screen size. How to fix this issue to show the whole NAV as a single element and never distort for increase or shrink the screen size?

Here is my site: http://hacksale.tk  (Just a demo site)

Comment: create global nav element set width:100% and then just float your elements , best way recode this nav correctly using ul li a thne just add li class logo and change style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">some link</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" class="logo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">some link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">some link</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
nav {
width:100%;
height:93px;
background-color:#767677;
padding:0 20px;
}
nav ul { list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0 }
nav ul li { float:left; margin-right:24px; position:realtive; }
nav ul li:last-child { margin-right:0; }
nav ul li a { display:block; height:93px; line-height:93px; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase; }
nav ul li a.logo { width:160px; height:160px; background:url('http://hacksale.tk/wp-content/themes/serene/images/logo.png'); position:relative; top:-30px; }
```

and here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/kLfjcseh/

Comment: WOW man. Thanks a lot. It worked like charm ! 
Can you tell me how can I edit your code to show all the elements in the Menu (Including Logo) to be in the center ?

Currently they are floating left.

Comment: u can add property width to nav ul, but first you need canculate all links size nav ul li a(width) , then change nav ul margin:0; to margin:0px auto; or you can do it all automatic with jquery http://jsfiddle.net/kLfjcseh/1/ update & and it's have some css update too

Answer (score -1):

**Here is your solution:**

Simply add following CSS3 properties in mentioned class and ID's, and please remove all float and position properties in the same:

```
#header {
        display: box;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -moz-box;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;
    }

.nav {
    display:block;
    margin-top:61px;
    }

#logo {
    display:block;
    }
```

If need more help, please most welcome :)